# QSerialPortInfo::serialNumber() always returns an empty string

Tags: c++, windows, qt, serial-port

**QSerialPortInfo::serialNumber()** always returns an empty string, which happens when it's unavailable.
I tried connecting different ports, everything seems allright, but it doesn't show a Serial Number of a port no matter what I do!
Port name, manufacturer, product ID, however, can be correctly outputted.

**I didn't connect any devices to the ports, however.**
**Why can serial number be unavailable? Can this be fixed somehow?**

I guess the mistake is somewhere outside code, but here is a slot that I use to access **serialNumber()** in :

```
void PortBrowser::onPortChange()
{
int i;
if(comsCombo->currentIndex()>-1)
    i =comsCombo->currentIndex();
else
    i = 0;

QSerialPort currPort(comsList[i]);

bool opened =  currPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

const QString seriNum = comsList[i].serialNumber();

serNum->setText(seriNum);
manufact->setText(comsList[i].manufacturer());
QTextStream out(stdout);
out<<comsList[i].serialNumber();
currPort.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `comsList`? Some `QList<QSerialPortInfo>`? If that's the case, I think we'll need more information on how you're constructing it. Regardless, it may just be unavailable per the documentation: "Returns the serial number string of the serial port, if available; otherwise returns an empty string." There can be any number of system-dependent reasons why it's unavailable. What platform is this for, Windows?

Comment: @dabbler it's QList of QSerialPortInfo. Yes, it's for Windows 10. If there's any specific information I should mention, I'd gladly do that

Comment: Does any of the other information output as expected? I.e. `portName()` or like you have pictured, `manufacturer()`?

Comment: @dabbler Yes, manufacturer, product Id do show up as expected if I try to output them, portname too.

Comment: Is `serialNumber` empty for every port in the list? Is there anything plugged into the port you're selecting?

Comment: @dabbler serialNumber() is an empty string for each of my ports, there's nothing plugged into them. I have 3 ports: defalut COM on the motherboard and 2 similar pl-2303hx's

Comment: I *think* `serialNumber` represents device-specific information, could be wrong there though. Try plugging something into the port, letting the system "discover" it, and then running your app to see if `serialNumber()` outputs anything.

Comment: @dabbler Ok, I will try that, but it'll take time, for I have no devices to connect them via these ports. Thx for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the relevant source code [parseDeviceSerialNumber()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialportinfo_win.cpp.html#_ZL23parseDeviceSerialNumberRK7QString) you will see quite some fancy logic where Qt tries to isolate a serial number from some device-identification string. That's the string you are likely also seeing in the Windows device manager way down in the details.

> Why can serial number be unavailable? Can this be fixed somehow?

You seem to have a serial port that does not provide its identifier in a format Qt would understand. You could try to come up with a patch for Qt to make it recognize your serial port or you might go and buy a serial port that Qt does recognize. One chipset that is explicitly mentioned in the source code is [FTDI](https://ftdichip.com/).